# How to trigger mCamera.autoFocus(myAutoFocusCallback) in AndEngineAugmentedRealityExtension?

Tags: android, andengine

In AndEngine AugmentedReality, I find that there is a "mCamera.autoFocus(myAutoFocusCallback);" function call inside CameraPreviewSurfaceView. How can I trigger this function so that I can have my AugmentedRealityExample's camera focus on something that is close to the camera? 
I have tried to tap on the screen in AugmentedRealityExample, but nothing happens. The camera didn't focus on anything.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally added an empty Entity whose size is them same as the screen to the Scene. Then make it clickable, and RegisterTouchArea(Entity) to implement what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the AndEngineAugmentedRealityExtension but if you want to trigger autoFocus by tapping on the screen, you have to set your own OnTouchListener in CameraPreviewSurfaceView.

In onTouch() you can call autoFocus(). If necessary, you can add your own AutoFocusCallback. Otherwise you can call autofocus(null).

Comment: AndEngineAugmentedRealityExtension already implements what you said. But I still cannot trigger autoFocus in onClick in SurfaceView.OnClickListener()

Comment: Why you cannot trigger it? You have to call the function yourself. Maybe your device has no autofocus?